# Define $u(x,y),v(x,y)$ by the implicit functions $x=f(u,v),y=g(u,v)$. Determine the formula for $\frac{du}{dx}$.

Tags: calculus

> Define $u(x,y),v(x,y)$ by the implicit functions $x=f(u,v),y=g(u,v)$. Determine the formula for $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$.

Comment: Are you supposed to be using partial derivatives?

Comment: Yes. I will fix all $d$ to $\partial$ using partial derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
x = f(u(x,y),v(x,y)) \Rightarrow 1 = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \label{x}\\
y = g(u(x,y),v(x,y)) \Rightarrow 0 = \frac{\partial g}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \label{y}
\end{eqnarray}
Solving,
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial g}{\partial v} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} \frac{\partial g}{\partial u} \right)^{-1}\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}$$